# How to find reactJS errors?

Tags: javascript, debugging, reactjs

I have been learning ReactJS a couple of days now but Im often ending up on a Server Error in '/' Application page that dont really point out where to lock for the problem. For example, this is a error I get right now :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

In file "~/Scripts/Grid.jsx": Parse Error: Line 106: Adjacent XJS elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (at line 106 column 58) Line: 52 Column:3

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: React.Exceptions.JsxException: In file "~/Scripts/Grid.jsx": Parse Error: Line 106: Adjacent XJS elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (at line 106 column 58) Line: 52 Column:3

Source Error: 


Line 8:  { Line 9:      <h2>Index</h2> Line 10:     @Html.React("GridBox", new Line 11:     { Line 12:         tableClass
= "GridTest",

Source File: c:\Development\Bradspel_v2\Bradspel_v2\Views\Home\Index.cshtml    Line: 10
```

The code looks like this :

```
var data1 = {"Columns":[{"Title":"Title1","HTMLClass":"g1_Title"},{"Title":"Title2","HTMLClass":"g2_Title"},{"Title":"Title3","HTMLClass":"g3_Title"}],"Rows":[{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]}]};


var GridRow = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var data = [], columns;

        if(this.props.columns){
            for(var i = 0; i < this.props.columns.length; i++){
                data.push({
                    HTMLclass: this.props.columns[i].HTMLClass,
                    content: this.props.cells[i]
                })
            }
        }


        columns = data.map(function(col, i) {
            return (
                <td className={col.HTMLclass} key={i}>{col.content}</td>
            );
        }.bind(this));

        return (
            <tr>
                {columns}
            </tr>
        );
    }
});
var GridHead = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        if(this.props.data){
            var cell = this.props.data.Title;
            var htmlClass = this.props.data.HTMLClass;
        }
        return (
            <th className={htmlClass}>{cell}</th>
        );
    }
});
var GridList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var tableClass = this.props.tableClass;
        if(this.props.data){
            var header = this.props.data.Columns.map(function (columns, i) {
                return (
                    <GridHead data={columns} key={i} />
                );
            });
            var row = this.props.data.Rows.map(function (row, i) {
                return ( **<<< HERE line 52**
                    <GridRow columns={data1.Columns} cells={row.Cells} key={i} />
                );
            });
        }
        return (
            <table className={tableClass}>
                <tr>{header}</tr>
                <tbody>
                    {row}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
});

var GridPager = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(event) {
        alert('clicked');
    },
    return: function() {

        var page


        return(
            <a onClick={this.handleClick}>Paging</a>
        );
    }
});


var GridBox = React.createClass({
    loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', this.props.url, true);
        xhr.onload = function() {
          var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          this.setState({ data: data });
        }.bind(this);
        xhr.send();
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { data: this.props.initial };
    },
    render: function(){
        var tableClass = this.props.tableClass;
        return (
            <GridList data={data1} tableClass={tableClass} />
            <GridPager>
        );
    }
});
```

There is a problem at line 106, this is the line direcly after the last line of code so this gives me nothing. Then we got a Line 52. I have marked the line 52 in above code(<<< HERE line 52) and you can see that there is only a return? So how am I really supose to manage to finde where the error really is?

Info : Im using Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET MVC 5 with ReactJS.NET and for editing jsx files Im using Sublime TEXT 3.

Comment: I personally like the chrome developer tools.  There is also a chrome developer tools plugin for react debugging.

Comment: Yes, its nice BUT this exception is thrown on serverside so there is no possibility to debug the code as far as I can see? All I get is a cryptic error message that points to the wrong line.

Answer (score 14):

React expects a single element to be returned from a render method.  A div needs to be wrapped around the components rendered in the GridBox render method return.  Also GridPager is missing its closing tag:

```
 render: function(){
    var tableClass = this.props.tableClass;
    return (
        <div>
            <GridList data={data1} tableClass={tableClass} />
            <GridPager/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I dont want a div there? I try to make my html slim? Even if I add the div I get the following exception : In file "~/Scripts/Grid.jsx": Parse Error: Line 110: Expected corresponding XJS closing tag for GridPager (at line 110 column 10)
Line: 52
Column:3

Comment: Okay I found that to, <GridPager> needs a <GridPager /> but the exception to yet again point me to wrong line nr!? The new exception now is : Error while loading "~/Scripts/Grid.jsx": Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 78
Column:5

Comment: It pointed to line 78 again where there is just a return( but the real error now was that the render at line 73 was named return, after this change the page works. But its a real pain to find these small mistakes, it will take forever to learn this if there is no better exception messages, right line should at least be correct. So the question remains, how do I debug and troubleshoot reactJS?

Comment: Reading this in the year 2015. Sure would be great if this question had a good answer.